# JS clock issue, to start onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i am building a game, and i need a counter. The counter needs to start onclick and when finishes just stops 00 (From 1m to 00).(Now it is starting onload, and when it reaches 00 it starts again).

HTML:

```
<body>
<div>
 <div class="timer" >Battle time: <span id="time"></span></div>
<p>BATTLE</p>
<BUTTON class="begin" onclick="" ><b>START</b></BUTTON>
</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var oneMinutes = 60 * 1,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(oneMinutes, display);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`clearinterval`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiesLjnyaHUAhXLwI8KHWsjAP4QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fmet_win_clearinterval.asp&usg=AFQjCNF5eXwLMatq9WhSrIXd736olamy2g&sig2=sfSfIXNbY_OeYJ-i85oIEA) after reach `00`.And apply with click function like this

```
onclick="startTimer(60,document.querySelector('#time'))"
```

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
 var timers = setInterval(runner, 1000);
 function runner() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
       clearInterval(timers)
    }
  }

}

window.onload = function() {
  var oneMinutes = 60 * 1,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(oneMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="timer">Battle time: <span id="time"></span></div>
    <p>BATTLE</p>
    <BUTTON class="begin" onclick="startTimer(60,document.querySelector('#time'))"><b>START</b></BUTTON>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clearInterval` to stop the interval.

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var handler = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            clearInterval(handler);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```